# running ranger on urvxt in i3 with bindsym

Tags: key-binding, i3-window-manager, xbindkeys

I am trying to use

```
bindsym $mod+Mod1+b exec "urxvt -e bash -c ranger"
```

in my i3-config. It runs but many features of ranger is not accessible, like,

1. I can't copy the file(/folder) path using `yp`
2. When I run `:shell some command` it gives me my `tmux zsh` and nothing happens.

Things work fine if I run it from gnome-terminal as `urvxt -e bash -c ranger` The only problem is when I call the terminal app via the bindsym, it doesn't work properly otherwise it does. I haven't changed ranger from it's default settings.

The Xdefaults file is [this](https://paste.debian.net/1081675/). The i3config file is [this](https://paste.debian.net/1081676/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
bindsym $mod+Mod1+b exec urxvt -e "ranger"
```

Mostly the command to execute within the application will be in quote.

Here `ranger` is the command to get executed inside urxvt. So `exec urxvt` will trigger `urxvt` and later `ranger` will be executed inside it